# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate - Opening Error Mac: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: intellij-idea, error-handling, startup

Installed the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and tried to open it but receive the error below (see code section). I am using macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.6) and installed IntelliJ IDEA Version 2017.3.3.
Can someone tell me how to solve this issue?

Many thanks.

```
Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0.0) or height (0.0) cannot be <= 0
at sun.awt.image.MultiResolutionCachedImage.checkSize(MultiResolutionCachedImage.java:79)
at sun.awt.image.MultiResolutionCachedImage.getResolutionVariant(MultiResolutionCachedImage.java:63)
at sun.awt.image.MultiResolutionCachedImage.getBaseImage(MultiResolutionCachedImage.java:122)
at java.awt.image.AbstractMultiResolutionImage.getWidth(AbstractMultiResolutionImage.java:69)

[[[... error continues ...]]]
```

Comment: You can try Intellij 2018.1 Maybe does it help you? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Answer (score 1):

I just restrated the system and - all of a sudden - it worked. (Please make also sure that you have the newest Java installed).